# How to sort a matrix by all columns

Tags: r, sorting

Suppose I have

```
arr = 2 1 3
      1 2 3
      1 1 2
```

How can I sort this into the below?

```
arr = 1 1 2
      1 2 3
      2 1 3
```

That is, first by column one, then by column two etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would work:

```
arr[do.call(order, lapply(1:NCOL(arr), function(i) arr[, i])), ]
```

What it is doing is:

```
arr[order(arr[, 1], arr[, 2], arr[ , 3]), ]
```

except it allows an arbitrary number of columns in the matrix.

Comment: Isn't the last column order redundant? I.e. 1:(NCOL(arr)-1) would do the same.

Comment: No, not in all matrices, such as `arr = matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1), nrow=3)`

Answer (score 21):

The function you're after is `order` (how I arrived at this conclusion -- my first thought was "well, sorting, what about `sort`?". Tried `sort(arr)` which looks like it sorts `arr` as a vector instead of row-wise. Looking at `?sort`, I see in the "See Also: `order` for sorting on or reordering **multiple** variables.").

Looking at `?order`, I see that `order(x,y,z, ...)` will order by `x`, breaking ties by `y`, breaking further ties by `z`, and so on. Great - all I have to do is pass in each column of `arr` to `order` to do this. (There is even an example for this in the examples section of `?order`):

```
order( arr[,1], arr[,2], arr[,3] ) 
# gives 3 2 1: row 3 first, then row 2, then row 1.
# Hence:
arr[ order( arr[,1], arr[,2], arr[,3] ), ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    2
#[2,]    1    2    3
#[3,]    2    1    3
```

Great!

---

But it is a bit annoying that I have to write out `arr[,i]` for *each* column in `arr` - what if I don't know how many columns it has in advance?

Well, the examples show how you can do this too: using `do.call`. Basically, you do:

```
do.call( order, args )
```

where `args` is a *list* of arguments into `order`. So if you can make a list out of each column of `arr` then you can use this as `args`.

One way to do this is is to convert `arr` into a data frame and then into a list -- this will automagically put one column per element of the list:

```
arr[ do.call( order, as.list(as.data.frame(arr)) ), ]
```

The `as.list(as.data.frame` is a bit kludgy - there are certainly other ways to create a list such that `list[[i]]` is the `i`th column of `arr`, but this is just one.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this little func that does decreasing order as well
cols allows to choose which columns to order and their order

```
ord.mat = function(M, decr = F, cols = NULL){
    if(is.null(cols))
      cols = 1: ncol(M)
    out = do.call( "order", as.data.frame(M[,cols]))
    if (decr)
      out = rev(out)
    return(M[out,])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and solution seems to be simple and elegant:

```
t(apply(t(yourMatrix),2,sort))
```