# R: initialise empty dgCMatrix given by matrix multiplication of two Quanteda DFM sparse matrices?

Tags: r, initialization, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, quanteda

I have for loop like this, trying to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594635/7301559), with dummy vars such that

```
aaa <- DFM %*% t(DFM)   #DFM is Quanteda dfm-sparse-matrix
for(i in 1:nrow(aaa)) aaa[i,] <- aaa[i,][order(aaa[i,], decreasing = TRUE)]
```

but now

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mmm)) mmm[i,] <- aaa[i,][order(aaa[i,], decreasing = TRUE)]
```

where `mmm` does not exist yet, the goal is to do the same thing as `mmm <- t(apply(a, 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE))`. But now before the for loop I need to initialise the `mmm` otherwise `Error: object 'mmm' not found`. The type of `aaa` and `mmm` is `dgCMatrix` given by the matrix multiplication of two Quanteda [DFM matrices](https://rdrr.io/cran/quanteda/man/dfm.html).

**Structure**

*`aaaFunc` is given by the matrix multiplication `DFM %*% t(DFM)` where DFM is the Quanteda Sparse dfm-matrix. The structure is such that*

> ```
> > str(aaaFunc)
> Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
>   ..@ i       : int [1:39052309] 0 2 1 0 2 2616 2880 3 4 5 ...
>   ..@ p       : int [1:38162] 0 2 3 7 8 10 13 15 16 96 ...
>   ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 38161 38161
>   ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:38161] "90120000" "90120000" "90120000" "86140000" ...
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:38161] "90120000" "90120000" "90120000" "86140000" ...
>   ..@ x       : num [1:39052309] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
>   ..@ factors : list()
> ```

*ERRORS* on the DFM with the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605723/r-best-way-to-replicate-an-object-of-same-size-and-type-as-other) on general question on replicating a R object without its content but its structure/etc.

> *A.* error with `aaaFunc.mt[]<- NA`
>
> ```
> > aaaFunc.mt <- aaaFunc[0,]; aaaFunc.mt[] <- NA; aaaFunc.mt[1,]
> Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : index larger than maximal 0
> ```
>
> *B.* error with `mySparseMatrix.mt[nrow(mySparseMatrix),]<-`
>
> ```
> > aaaFunc.mt <- aaaFunc[0,]; aaaFunc.mt[nrow(aaaFunc),] <- NA
> Error in intI(i, n = di[margin], dn = dn[[margin]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
>   index larger than maximal 0
> ```
>
> *C.* error with `replace(...,NA)`
>
> ```
> Browse[2]> mmmFunc <- replace(aaaFunc,NA);
> Error in replace(aaaFunc, NA) : 
>   argument "values" is missing, with no default
> Browse[2]> mmmFunc <- replace(aaaFunc,,NA);
> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, list, value = NA) : 
>   argument "list" is missing, with no default
> Browse[2]> mmmFunc <- replace(aaaFunc,c(),NA);
> Error in .local(x, i, j, ..., value) : 
>   not-yet-implemented 'Matrix[<-' method
> ```

**How do you initialise empty dgCMatrix given by the matrix multiplication of two Quanteda DFM matrices?**

Comment: What dimensions of dfm do you want to initialize, and what should be the initial values (is zero ok?).

Comment: @KenBenoit Added the Structure to the body of the question, such as `Dimnames: List of 2`, given by the matrix multiplication of two Quanteda dfm-martices. The initial values probably needs to be of the same type as the earlier value.

Comment: Judging by your usecase, you could use `mmm = aaa` and, then, use your code -- this will not affect `aaa`. If you need something else, you could manipulate a duplicate object like `mmm = aaa; mmm@x = vector(typeof(aaa@x), length(aaa@x)); any other slot you need to change; ...`

Comment: Too hard to follow your question without a reproducible example and the output you are seeking. But you can "initialize" a dfmSparse this way: `nc <- 20; nr <- 30; wikiDfm <- new("dfmSparse", Matrix::Matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = nc, dimnames = list(docs = paste0("doc", 1:nr), features = paste0("feat", 1:nc)), sparse = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

The following will either initialize an empty sparse matrix or reset an existing sparse matrix while preserving both the dimensions and `dimnames`

```
library(Matrix)

i <- c(1,3:8)
j <- c(2,9,6:10)
x <- 7 * (1:7)
A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)
rownames(A) <- letters[seq_len(nrow(A))]

A2 <- sparseMatrix(i = integer(0), j = integer(0), dims = A@Dim, dimnames = A@Dimnames)

A@i <- integer(0)
A@p[] <- 0L
A@x <- numeric(0)

setequal(A, A2)
[1] TRUE
```