# R: Best way to replicate an object of same size and type as other?

Tags: r, variables, initialization, sparse-matrix, variable-declaration

Suppose you have some R object, such data.frame and Quanteda DFM sparse matrix. You want to replicate that object of the same size but no need to copy the content.

Is there some R command to replicate any object without copying the content? And if yes, do they work over sparse objects and non-sparse objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will create the same data structure filled with `NA`

```
data("iris")
iris.mt <- iris[0, ]
iris.mt[nrow(iris), ] <- NA

str(iris.mt)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Comment: `iris.mt[] <- NA` will do it - no need to select columns or rows.

Comment: You could also use `replace` to run identical code in a single line `iris.mt <- replace(iris,,NA)`

Comment: @latemail using `iris.mt[] <- NA` drops the factors if that is desired to be maintained.  Although using `replace` as you suggest is faster.

Comment: This fails for example with the `dgCMatrix` object [here](http://pastie.org/private/yxkrf6e6epvwrgxowcwma).

Comment: @thelatemail that does not work with the `dgCMatrix` object [here](http://pastie.org/private/xtmhmohjk79qq1ciq4otqq).

Comment: @manotheshark I tried that as well with `dgCMatrix` failing with `aaaFunc.mt <- aaaFunc[0,]; aaaFunc.mt[] <- NA; aaaFunc.mt[1,]` causing `Error in intI(i, n = x@Dim[1], dn[[1]], give.dn = FALSE) : 
  index larger than maximal 0`?

Comment: Apparently this `dgCMatrix`, generated by the matrix multiplication of two Quanteda sparse matrices, is very different from the basic R's data frames so focus on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596273/r-initialise-empty-dgcmatrix-given-by-matrix-multiplication-of-two-quanteda-dfm) while this thread on this more general, more typical R issue.